# What are valid statements inside a python eval()?

Tags: python, eval

I have tried

```
eval('print("hello world")')
eval('return 0')
```

which are both incorrect. Why are they invalid and what rules should I follow when using `eval()` (other than as little as possible)?

Comment: The former would work in Python 3.x and is "likely the wrong way to use print" in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python, `eval()` evaluates *expressions* (something that results in a value). Both `print` and `return` are defined as *statements* (however in Python 3, `print` is actually a function call, which is an expression). In the case of executing statements, you need to use [the `exec` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-exec_stmt) instead.

Comment: if I use exec('return 0') inside an except block it reports back as a SyntaxError: 'return' outside function, even though it's inside one. Why?

Comment: Because inside the `exec`, there is no function (the code is run inside a different execution context, as if it were loaded from its own separate source file).

Comment: It is not possible to directly cause a caller to return (it would be like function `f()` calling `g()`, and then `g()` doing something that somehow causes `f()` to return a value). What you can do is use `eval()` to run some external code, then depending on the value of what is returned from `eval()`, you can decide to `return` something from your function, or not.

Answer (score 0):

**eval() is used to evaluate a value of a varaible as a variable.**

example:

```
var="Hello World!"
code="var"
print eval(code)
```

output should be:

```
Hello World!
```