# Why do eval('break') and eval('continue') fail?

Tags: python, python-2.7, eval

I have a loop which runs until the user presses Ctrl+C.

The user is then asked to input y/n.

If the user presses `'y'`, then I do `eval('continue')`.

If the user presses `'n'`, then I do `eval('break')`.

```
while True:
    try:
        ...
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ...
        options = {'y':'continue','n':'break'}
        while True:
            decision = raw_input('continue (y/n)?')
            if decision in options:
                break
        eval(options[decision])
```

When I press `'y'`, I get:

```
    continue
           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

When I press `'n'`, I get:

```
    break
           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Can somebody please explain what am I missing here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851389/what-are-valid-statements-inside-a-python-eval

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eval()` only evaluates *expressions*. `break` and `continue` are not expressions, they are [(simple) statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html).

You can't run such statements from a variable here; the compiler needs to know *up front* where such statements are going to be used, because there are jump offsets involved in the bytecode. Just use `if` tests:

```
if decision == 'y':
    continue
elif decision == 'n':
    break
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: goodvibration is hardly new to SO and they asked and accepted questions before :-) The question is not yet 15 minutes old so they *can't* just yet.